# Fetch fork of a huge Github repository without redownloading unmodified files

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I cloned a repository from Github with this commmand: `git clone https://github.com/user1/huge_repo`. This repo is huge, multiple gigabytes.

Someone made a small edit to one of the files and pushed their fork on Github. I want to fetch their version of the repo (let's say, it's on `https://github.com/user2/huge_repo`) without downloading gigabytes of data that are unmodified. Is this possible?

Comment: you can set their url for pull locally 
```git remote set-url origin git.com.etc.whatever```
and for push set your own
```git remote set-url --push origin your.repo```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your existing clone as a *reference clone*.  For instance, if your existing clone lives in `$HOME/sources/github.com/user1/huge_repo`:

```
git clone --reference $HOME/sources/github.com/user1/huge_repo https://github.com/user2/huge_repo
```

You may wish to add `--dissociate` here, or not; that part is up to you.  With or without `--dissociate`, your Git asks the GitHub Git what commits they have to send you.  This makes a list of commits to fetch.  Let's assume for concreteness that the list includes `a123456`.  Your Git now:

- looks at the reference clone's objects to see if you already have commit `a123456`:

  - if yes, uses the existing copy and tells the other Git *no thanks, I already have that commit*, which avoids downloading it at all
  - if no, tells the other Git *yes please, send `a123456`* (which makes it offer the parents of `a123456`, and we add those to the list of commits to check).

Your Git repeats this for all the commits needed, including those added because your Git said *yes, please send that one*.  The result is the set of objects you must download, plus a list of hash IDs that you can borrow or steal from the reference clone.

Their Git (GitHub's) packages up the commits and supporting objects that must be sent, knowing which commits your Git has said you already have.  So you get only *new* objects, not existing ones, and furthermore, those new objects can be delta-compressed against your existing objects.

*Now* the `--dissociate` flag comes into play.  If you *did not* use it, your Git stores, in your `user2/huge_repo` clone, an "alternates" entry that lists the *path name in which the objects you're borrowing live*.  The effect of this is that you're now borrowing them for the foreseeable future: some time in the future, you might try to use a commit or supporting object from *this* clone that you didn't actually *clone*.  You *borrowed it* from the reference.

Your Git software will go *back to the reference clone* and try to use that object from there.  If it's still there, everything works, but if something has happened to that reference clone—such as removing it entirely *or* merely discarding the referenced object *from* that clone because it was unused there—then your `user2/huge_repo` clone may become unusable.  (You can restore the usability by retrieving the missing object, as long as there's some place to get it *from*.)

If, on the other hand, you *did* use `--dissociate`, your Git will, having cloned `user2/huge_repo` with reference to the reference clone, now *copy* the reference clone's objects into your new clone.  This means the original reference clone can be removed, or have objects collected out of it, without damaging the new clone.

If you can guarantee that objects won't vanish from the reference clone, you can leave it in place and save disk space—potentially quite a bit.  If not, you'll probably want to spend the disk space up front, to avoid having to repair a broken repository later.

(GitHub work around this kind of problem by never expiring any objects by default.  That's why you have to ask them to remove sensitive data.)